# graphhopper how ofter the map database is updated

Tags: routes, openstreetmap, graphhopper

how often graphhopper updates the map from the openstreetmap and included in its routing algorithm
 I added one road two days back, in openstreetmap and graphhopper map the road is showing, but when i try to route between two points, its not taking the newly added road

the points get shifted to nearest old road and also routing goes through the old road, which was longer n distance

http://graphhopper.com/maps/?point=10.013207%2C76.291938&point=10.015923%2C76.301744

you can see the above map, i added the roads, valiaparambu road, kerala , india  and B.T.S road

thanks for the support
Dino

Comment: Just wait a little longer. Because GraphHopper uses contraction hierarchies it has to do a little more pre-processing compared to conventional routers and thus may take a little longer to update its data.

Comment: Hey Dino, thanks for you interests. I fear this does not count as real stackoverflow question :) (mailing list is always appropriate though). And currently we have no regular update interval - will be changed soon to daily.

Comment: thanks for the reply .  so if i am hosting it in my server, how can i do the updation so that when i add new roads it will get reflected to the routing algorithm ?

Comment: Please see the documentation, dev or user quickstart: https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/blob/master/docs/index.md

Answer (score 1):

Creating an anwser: we have no regular update interval - will be changed to daily.